# Descendant Enumeration in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, runtime, metaprogramming

Is it possible to get a list of all descendant classes of a particular class in objective-c?

Something like:

```
  @interface A : NSObject
  @end

  @interface B : A
  @end

  @interface C : A
  @end

  NSArray *descendants = [A allDescendants];  // descendants = [B, C]
```

Answer (score 5):

The only way I can think is to enumerate the entire list of classes in the runtime (obtained with `objc_getClassList`) and test each one for `isKindOfClass:A`.

This is likely the only solution because classes do not maintain links to their descendants (only to their superclass).

Answer (score 1):

As an example I am linking to [solution](http://homepage.mac.com/kenferry/temp/WilShipleyInitChallenge.html) by [Ken Ferry](http://homepage.mac.com/kenferry/) to a [Wil Shipley](http://www.wilshipley.com/blog/2005/07/self-stupid-init.html) blog post.

Essentially, walking the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the class member somehow? Calling `[[A class] superclass]` returns an instance of the `Class` class for self's superclass. I think that you can get the name of a class from its `Class` - would that do what you want?

This doesn't really handle Protocols at all, but maybe  this will point you in the right direction at least.